# Coordinate Systems in Files (pixels)

Tags: filesystems

I'm trying to solve the problem of transferring data from a pdf file to another file type.  When extracting data from PDF files I am to use the exact coordinates (where each unit is 1/72 of an inch in a pdf file) to the same position in another file type.  Say a text file or a word document etc?

I'm having trouble making the connection between this coordinate system and the file type I'm transferring data to.

Is there a way to make a quasi coordinate system in a text file or word document or a rich text file?  What about an output console.  I thought there might be some conventions used which govern how many pixels a space is in these documents?  For example if I have a space between characters in my pdf which has a difference of 8 x 1/72 of an inch it may just be kerning as opposed to a word space.  I'm not sure how to tell the difference and use that in my destination file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with computer *science*.

Comment: Same point.  This information is important for extracting and replacing text from files in programming.  It's the only place you can ask this kind of question.

Comment: Even if that were true, it would not make the question ontopic here. Note how programming != computer science. Programming questions have a home over at [SO].